# Como configurar el windowbuilder eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, windowbuilder

alguien sabe como configurar el windowbuilder, para que salga los metodos abajo del codigo y estea ordenado ? como por ejemplo: al dar doble click sobre un boton y debe generar el metodo debajo y no entreverado.

Java: 11
Eclipse Version :2021-09 (4.21.0)

Esta es la configuracion que tengo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se porque se genera el codigo de esta manera, cuando le doy doble click a un boton para crear el metodo, no ordena el codigo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontre la forma para que se ordene el codigo de manera automatica:

1. Click en 'Window'
2. Click en 'Preferences'
3. Desplegar 'WindowBuilder'
4. Desplegar 'Swing'
5. Click en 'Code Generation'
6. Darle Check al 'Field'
7. Click en 'Apply'
8. Desplegar 'Code Generation'
9. Click en 'Event Handlers'
10. Darle Check en 'Implements Listener Interface in Parent Class'
11. Darle Check al 'Create Stub Event Handler Methods Named'
12. Seleccionar en el combo 'do_${component_name}_${event_name}
13. Click en 'Apply'

Este seria el resultado si le dan doble click a algun boton, para implementar un metodo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]